# To include my current 2 weeks working experience or not in the resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, job-change

I have joined a an Enterprise company since 2 weeks as Senior Software Engineer (**It's a permanent position**), despite the fact that I have learned a lot since I have joined, but I can't wait to get myself out of this environment. ( I don't want to go through why I feel like that in this question)

My question is : Should I include the current position I am holding in this company and the things I have worked on so far?

Or, Should I completely ignore this position in my resume and just adjust my previous position with the things I have discovered here?

Obviously, at the end of the day, I will tell my future employer to know where I am working currently. My concern is just the first impression of the hiring manager when he/she sees my resume.

**P.S : Over the past 2 weeks I have learnt enormously on few new technologies that I wasn't familiar with in the past, thus it's important for me to include these either by stating my current position (2 weeks), OR Including what I have learn in these 2 weeks in my previous position.**

Answer (score 2):

I guess basically **you have to include your current job**. Because if you leave it out and for whatever reason **someone finds out** that you had that job then this will raise questions like: **Why didn't he mention it? What else did he not tell us?** And in some cases it might give them a reason to fire you because you didn't tell the whole truth.

If you want to avoid it then maybe you get away with that for a few weeks because your sent out your "old" resume which you "forgot" to update with your latest position. But that won't work for long and is clearly not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I am with the most stupid person on this one, but for a different reason.

Don't include two ***weeks*** on your CV/resume because ... what is the purpose of a cv/resume?

I would say that it is too tell a prospective employer what you can bring to them. I would further say that you are highly unlikely to learn enough new stuff in two weeks, that you don't have from other positions, to be helpful to a future employer.

If asked about it later, explain just that.

Background: I had one perm position a few decades ago, so may not be up on the nuances. As a developer of embedded systems, I am generally handed a bunch of "stuff to read" at the start of each new contract and expected to slowly start becoming productive after 3 to 4 weeks (longer for perms, imo). That's on projects with 8 to 15 developers. My current project is developing s/w for a military satellite and we were told that we are not expected to be productive for 3 months (!).

**Tl;dr** did you really do or learn anything new in those two whole weeks that could be of benefit to a future employer?

Comment: I have learnt enormously over the past 2 weeks and I can see these 2 weeks has expended my technical horizon. (I know I am sounding a bit exaggerated) which is why I throughout of including what I have in these 2 weeks into my previous job.

Comment: If you say so (+1); then, perhaps you should state that in the question, to help others to give the best advice possible. I am having difficulty picturing it, to be honest, but you should know better than me. If you had said that in the original question, then I would not have posted this answer.

Comment: my apology. I have edited my question.

Comment: No need to apologize. This isn't quite GIGP :-) but the more relevant info we have, the better we can help you

Comment: For GIGP, please read GIGO :-)

Comment: However, I am still disinclined to believe that you really ***learned*** much in two weeks, let alone have experience using it - and would tell you so if I were interviewing you.  If this experience really would be so useful, then I suggest that you tough it out for at least a year, then you will sound convincing at an interview.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I don't include my current position and I won't tell I am working currently in the interview also. I will tell that now I am looking for a job.

The main reason for that is, most companies (At least in my country) don't like persons who changes jobs very frequency.

If they asked why you resigned before find new job I will said that It is hard to find jobs / go interviews because of limited leaves and workload. And I will mention that financially I am OK or I am currently doing freelancing works too find a new job.

If they asked when you can join us I will say I need to finish the freelancing works already started, so I need X weeks (Tell the notice period of current job ) of time.

Comment: That might be risky. Because if someone finds out he can be in trouble for giving wrong information. For some companies that could be constructed as a breach of confidence - fired.